# Custom Implementation of AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter

Tags: spring-mvc

I want to customize below method in AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter which is used in mapping annotated methods in spring.

public static boolean checkHeaders(String[] headers, HttpServletRequest request) {}

How can I configure in spring to to pick up my adapter in which I have overridden checkHeaders method.

Answer (score 2):

It's normally the job of the `<mvc:annotation-driven />` tag to automatically register the `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter` and associated beans in the application context.

If you want to manually register your own custom `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter` subclass then you should remove the `<mvc:annotation-driven />` tag and declare the custom bean in your dispatcher-servlet.xml.

```
<bean class="some.package.MyCustomAnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="someProperty" value="someValue"/>
</bean>
```

If you don't remove `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` then you'll get two `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter` beans in the application context - and your custom one will be ignored.

There's a very good post [here](http://scottfrederick.cfapps.io/blog/2011/03/11/Customizing-Spring-3-mvc-annotation-driven/) that talks about customizing a `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter` and lays out an alternative approach using a `BeanPostProcessor` to modify the default `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter` in-place.

It's also worth pointing out that `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter` is deprecated in Spring 3.2 in favor of `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter`

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same troubles as Will described and come to solution, which is IMHO a little bit simpler and more compact than proposed in article [here](http://scottfrederick.cfapps.io/blog/2011/03/11/Customizing-Spring-3-mvc-annotation-driven/):

@Component("customHttpMessageConverter")
public class DemoHttpMessageConverter extends MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter {

```
@Autowired
AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter handlerAdapter; // <-- will be injected by Spring

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    // here the field 'handlerAdapter' is already injected
    // and you can either extend or substitute the list of message-converters
    handlerAdapter.setMessageConverters(new HttpMessageConverter[] {this});
}

@Override
public boolean canRead(Class<?> clazz, MediaType mediaType) {
    // we use JAXB in our project, but you can provide your own logic here
    // or just return 'true' if you are sure that @ResponseBody and @RequestBody are used properly      
    return clazz.isAnnotationPresent(XmlRootElement.class);
}

@Override
public boolean canWrite(Class<?> clazz, MediaType mediaType) {
    // ... the same as with 'canRead' ...
    return clazz.isAnnotationPresent(XmlRootElement.class);
}

@Override
protected Object readInternal(Class<?> clazz, HttpInputMessage inputMessage) throws IOException, HttpMessageNotReadableException {
    String inputMessageStr = IOUtils.toString(inputMessage.getBody());
    return customDeserialize(inputMessageStr);
}

@Override
protected void writeInternal(Object obj, HttpOutputMessage outputMessage) throws IOException, HttpMessageNotWritableException {
    String outputMessageStr = customSerialize(inputMessageStr);
    IOUtils.write(outputMessageStr, outputMessage.getBody(), JsonEncoding.UTF8.getJavaName());
}

public Object customDeserialize(String json) {
    // your own de-serialization 
}

public String customSerialize(Object obj) {
    // your own serialization 
}
```

}

Comment: I will appreciate if someone correct the format of java-fragment in my post.